# how to decrease all the elements of a column in a text file from each other?

Tags: python, database, text

I have a text file with two columns and 135001 rows. First column is amplitude and second column is related time. I need to go over the first column and understand where the amplitude increase and again decrease and I need to extract the related time. Actually I should make a derivate from first column. When the amplitude increases I should count one and then I should wait until the amplitude reach zero, then again do this process. As I mentioned I need the related time also. This is a very raw code that I am thinking of that and i know it is not true but I do not know how to complete it. For the first step I have problem with decreasing the rows in the first column and I got this error" str could not convert to float".

```
n=0
with open('39-1+2.txt',"r") as f
for line in f

    data=line.split(' ')[0]
    time=line.split(' ')[1]

    with open ('grad-time.txt', 'w') as s:
        for i in range (0, 135001):
        if
        d= float(data[i+1])-float (data[i])>0
        n=n+1
        s.write("{}\n".format(d))
        wait
        float(data [i]= 0.0)
        continue
```

For an example I have this file:

```
0 11
2 12
3 13
1 14
0 15
1 16
0 17
0 18
```

The out put should be like:

```
2 12
1 16
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 3 13 instead of 2 12 since the amplitude continues to increase after 2 12 ?

Comment: I need the first point that amplitude start to increase.

Comment: I think it might be good if you clarify the question. Right now it's unclear to me what you mean by 'decrease all the elements'. Also, your example suggests that you want to include a threshold as well since you don't consider the 1 at t=16.

Comment: It would be good if you could fix your code to make clearer what you are trying. currently it has a lot of syntax errors

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to fix the code. But in the first step i should do this : "data[i+1])-float (data[i]" , but I will have the error" string could not convert to float". So it seams that with my code it is reading the lines as string and not as numbers to can decrease them from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use the value of a previous row to make decision on the current row, you can make use of pandas' `shift`.  This will allow you to create a new column that holds the value of the previous row.

Using that logic you just need to check if the previous row is 0, and that the current value is higher than that.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0,11],[2,12],[3,13],[1,14],[0,15],[1,16],[0,17],[0,18]])
>>> df['shift'] = df[0].shift(1)
>>> df
   0   1  shift
0  0  11    NaN
1  2  12    0.0
2  3  13    2.0
3  1  14    3.0
4  0  15    1.0
5  1  16    0.0
6  0  17    1.0
7  0  18    0.0
>>> df[(df['shift']==0) & (df[0] > df['shift'])].drop(columns=['shift'])
   0   1
1  2  12
5  1  16
```

Comment: How can I store the output in a text file? I am using "s.write ("{}\n".format(df))" but it will store it like it print it and do not shows all the rows, it put ... instead of many rows.

Comment: That is a different question altogether.  Perhaps upvote and mark this is the correct answer since it fully addresses our original question.  Then look for how to import text to pandas, and how to write pandas dataframes to csv. There are millions of examples on here.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but the following functions should work for your problem:

```
def prepare_date(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.readlines()

    prepared_data = []
    for line in data:
        # A line "1 16" becomes [1, 16] in prepared_data
        prepared_data.append(
            [int(item) for item in line.split()]
        )

    return prepared_data

def find_increases_in_amplitude(prepared_data):
    # get the first data point
    last_data_point = prepared_data[0]

    increases = []

    # loop over data and find increases
    for data_point in prepared_data:
        # if the last data point had amplitude 0, and the current has amplitude 
        # greater than zero: store the data_point in "increases"
        if last_data_point[0] == 0 and data_point[0] > 0:
            increases.append(data_point)

        # update last_data_point
        last_data_point = data_point

    return increases
```

If you use the first one to open and prepare your data (make it a list like `[ [1, 12], ...]` ), then run that list through the second function.